# R- Subtract values of all rows in a group from previous row in different group and filter out rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In R say I had the data frame:

```
data

frame object  x      y
1     6       150    100
2     6       149    99
3     6       148    98
3     6       140    90
4     6       148.5  97    
4     6       142    93
5     6       147    96    
5     6       138    92
5     6       135    90
6     6       146.5  99
1     7       125    200
2     7       126    197
3     7       127    202
3     7       119    185
4     7       117    183    
4     7       123    199
5     7       115    190    
5     7       124    202
5     7       118    192
6     7       124.5  199
```

I want to output the object which is the closest in the previous frame based on the (x,y) coordinates and filter out the other objects. I want to find the difference in the x and y between all the objects in a given frame and the single object in the previous frame and keep the closest object while removing the rest. The object that is kept would then serve as reference for the next frame. The frames with only one object would be left as is. The output should be one object per frame:

```
data

frame object  x      y
1     6       150    100
2     6       149    99
3     6       148    98
4     6       148.5  97    
5     6       147    96    
6     6       146.5  99
1     7       125    200
2     7       126    197
3     7       127    202    
4     7       123    199    
5     7       124    202
6     7       124.5  199
```

Comment: Give example for a frame like 3 object 6 to define closest.

Comment: When you say "closest", do you want to use Euclidean distance, or sum the absolute difference, or some other distance metric?

Comment: @GregorThomas Forgot to put that, but sum the absolute difference

Comment: @MohamedDesouky I would want to sum the absolute difference so |148-149| =1 and |98-99| =1 and |140-149|=9 and |90-99|=9 so I would want the object with coordinates (148,98) and discard (140,90)

Comment: Is that `abs(148-149) + abs(98-99)`? It needs to be reduced to a single number

Comment: @r2evans Yes that would be correct

Answer (score 2):

We can create a `for` loop that applies the criteria to a single object, and then use `group_by %>% summarize` to apply it to every object:

```
library(dplyr)

keep_closest_frame = function(data) {
  frames = split(data, dd$frame)
  for(i in seq_along(frames)) {
    if(nrow(frames[[i]]) != 1 & i == 1) {
      stop("First frame must have exactly 1 row")
    }
    if(nrow(frames[[i]]) == 1) next
    dists = with(frames[[i]], abs(x - frames[[i - 1]][["x"]]) + abs(y - frames[[i - 1]][["y"]]))
    frames[[i]] = frames[[i]][which.min(dists), ]
  }
  bind_rows(frames)
}


data %>%
  group_by(object) %>%
  summarize(keep_closest_frame(across()))
# # A tibble: 12 × 4
# # Groups:   object [2]
#    object frame     x     y
#     <int> <int> <dbl> <int>
#  1      6     1  150    100
#  2      6     2  149     99
#  3      6     3  148     98
#  4      6     4  148.    97
#  5      6     5  147     96
#  6      6     6  146.    99
#  7      7     1  125    200
#  8      7     2  126    197
#  9      7     3  127    202
# 10      7     4  123    199
# 11      7     5  124    202
# 12      7     6  124.   199
```

Comment: This is what I was hoping for, didn't get to incorporating dplyr soon enough. Nice job, GregorThomas.

Comment: I haven't done something quite like this since `do` was deprecated, but I thought it should be doable with the new `summarize`. I've never done `foo(across())` before, but it seems like it has powerful potential.

Comment: Seems nice, I thought `cur_data()` was preferred and canonical, but `across()` seems both a little quizzical yet succinct at the same time ... as if "across nothing" is translated into `across(everything())` without the rlang-expression(s).

Comment: btw, I was trying to preserve order of the rows (yours can miss it too), but I think your implementation here does a better job of keeping them together/grouped.

Comment: I **think** that if the input is sorted by frame my output should be sorted by frame too... or am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct ... I'm thinking of preserving the original order regardless of the order of data within it. Yours reorders due to `split` and `bind_rows`. I wonder if it's possible to use `\`split<-\`` somehow to get it back in the original order ... if that's critical, that is, since I think for the most part it's just my OCD :-)

Comment: Ah, I see. My solution would be to add a check for the order and throw a warning or error if the input wasn't ordered ;)

Comment: Yeah, I followed the example at `?do` which uses `foo(across())`, but that may be more out-of-date than `cur_data()`. That said, I like the idea of using select helpers within `across()`, which seems cleaner than `cur_data() %>% select(...)`

Answer (score 2):

This is a cumulative operation, so it'll take an iterative approach. Here's a simple function to do one operation, assuming it's for only one `object`.

```r
fun <- function(Z, fr) {
  prevZ <- head(subset(Z, frame == (fr-1)), 1)
  thisZ <- subset(Z, frame == fr)
  if (nrow(prevZ) < 1 || nrow(thisZ) < 2) return(Z)
  ind <- which.min( abs(thisZ$x - prevZ$x) + abs(thisZ$y - prevZ$y) )
  rbind(subset(Z, frame != fr), thisZ[ind,])
}

fun(subset(dat, object == 6), 3)
#    frame object     x   y
# 1      1      6 150.0 100
# 2      2      6 149.0  99
# 5      4      6 148.5  97
# 6      4      6 142.0  93
# 7      5      6 147.0  96
# 8      5      6 138.0  92
# 9      5      6 135.0  90
# 10     6      6 146.5  99
# 3      3      6 148.0  98
```

(The order is not maintained, it can easily be sorted back into place as needed.)

Now we can `Reduce` this for each `object` within the data.

```r
out <- do.call(rbind,
  lapply(split(dat, dat$object),
         function(X) Reduce(fun, seq(min(X$frame)+1, max(X$frame)), init=X)))
out <- out[order(out$object, out$frame),]
out
#      frame object     x   y
# 6.1      1      6 150.0 100
# 6.2      2      6 149.0  99
# 6.3      3      6 148.0  98
# 6.5      4      6 148.5  97
# 6.7      5      6 147.0  96
# 6.10     6      6 146.5  99
# 7.11     1      7 125.0 200
# 7.12     2      7 126.0 197
# 7.13     3      7 127.0 202
# 7.16     4      7 123.0 199
# 7.18     5      7 124.0 202
# 7.20     6      7 124.5 199
```

Comment: It's fun to see the little differences.